# Is the strong convergence of Borel probability measure metrizable?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

In a metric space $(X,e)$, a sequence of Borel probability measure converges strongly, $\mu_i \xrightarrow{s} \mu$, iff for each Borel subset $S \in X$, we have $\lim_{i \to \infty}\mu_i(S) = \mu(S)$.

Is there a metric $d$ on $\Delta(X)$, the space of all Borel probability measures on $X$, such that if $\lim_{i \to \infty}d(\mu_i,\mu)=0$, then $\mu_i \xrightarrow{s} \mu$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can define the metric
$$\rho(\mu,\nu):=\sup_{B\in\mathcal B(X)}|\mu(A)-\nu(B)|.$$
Then $\rho(\mu_i,\mu)\to 0$ *implies* that $\mu_i(B)\to \mu(B)$ for each $B\in\mathcal B(X)$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your lucid answer!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I don't understand the argument for why strong convergence is not metrizable. How do you identify the space of Borel probability measures with the space of functions from the real line to $[0,1]$? By the way, $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is countable if and only if it is finite.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker You are right, the argument does not work. I removed it.